# Event not registred

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I use thymeLeaf.

In a fragment I have:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#giTable").bootstrapTable();
     $('[id^=setterSelect]').on('change paste keyup', function (e) {
         ....
     });
  });
</script>

<form id="npF" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
 <select class="form-control" id="setterSelect0" parent-type="c.s.t.model.spi" parent-id="1" datatype="bdp_id">
  <option value="380">Sita</option>
  <option value="381">TCF</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

There is no event registered for `setterSelect0` and I don't understand why.

Edit

In chrome, after the page is loaded, if I go into the console and type:

```
$('[id^=setterSelect]').on('change paste keyup', function (e) {
                  ....
});
```

it works.

Comment: Did you debug it? Does it find the element ? `console.log($('[id^=setterSelect]').length)`

Comment: use your debugger! the reason is not in the code shown, so you have another troublemaker, which you can find with debugging.

Answer (score -2):

It is working in my case.

Hope your `$("#giTable").bootstrapTable();` is not creating any problem.
Do you have any error in console? or try to debug by commenting the `bootstrapTable()` as I did in the below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //$("#giTable").bootstrapTable();

  $('[id^=setterSelect]').on('change paste keyup', function(e) {
    console.log('herer');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="npF" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
  <select class="form-control" id="setterSelect0" parent-type="c.s.t.model.spi" parent-id="1" datatype="bdp_id">
    <option value="380">Sita</option>
    <option value="381">TCF</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a question which should have been made in a comment.

Comment: try my code, if it won't work then ask me the question. And the question related to the debugging is already been asked. I have just posted the working code.

Comment: Can you accept the answer and vote it up if it helped?